# Connecting a SainSmart 9-in HDMI Touchscreen?

Tags: driver, touchscreen

What's involved in connecting a SainSmart 9 inch HDMI touchscreen to a Pi? There seems to be a lot involved in getting *any* touchscreen working, with not much information out - and some of that contradictory.

For instance, SainSmart's description says, "No need to install a driver" - but everything I've seen, indicates that the stock Raspbian doesn't contain built-in drivers.

For instance, [Circuit Basics](http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/) says:

> The standard version of Raspbian does not include the drivers for LCD touchscreens

and then gives instructions on how to install them. (Granted, this article could be out-of-date).

When I downloaded the SainSmart tutorials, it had a *setup.sh* that would install... drivers. Which is fine, but reading the code, it has the prompt:

```
Which interface of controller do you use?
(I) [1] RS232 [2] PS/2 [3] USB:
```

Ah, I wanted to use *HDMI*, since that's what the touchscreen was advertised...

Has anyone actually gotten one of these to work, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same touch screen controller that they have used for running their touch screen. It should work out of the box. You can select USB in those options and give it a go.

Also, when you connect it to USB port, try running lsusb. There should be eGalax something device listed in it. It means it's detected as a device.

Hope it helps.

========================================================================

Edit :

I think Raspbian does include eGalax drivers by default now. I had a look at my electronics junk box and found the same module. Connected to USB of Rpi.

See attached.

[image]

Comment: `lsusb` is a good suggestion, but I'm trying to figure out what's involved before buy one. :) Also - are you saying that no drivers were required? I thought raspbian did not have built-in drivers.

Comment: @JohnC Answer edited. See the snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

HDMI is only to show picture. You (usually) need to connect touch separately. Looks like you can use USB port to connect touchscreen part.
Try with that.

I have played with SainSmarts 7" touchscreen but could not get it working with touchscreen and they are very unresponsive so I resorted to buying another one from competition.